# Solving a tricky equation involving logs

Tags: calculus

How can you solve

$$a(1 - 1/c)^{a - 1} = a - b$$

for $a$?

I get $(a-1)\ln(1-1/c) = \ln(1-b/a)$ and then I am stuck.

All the variables are real and $c>a>b>1$.

Comment: both are with base 2  right

Comment: I may be mistaken but your equation is of the form $ap^a + qa + r = 0$ for some $p, q, r$, which is of course somehow solvable but I don't see any "precalculus" here..

Comment: I don't think this equation is solvable for $\,a\,$ in terms of simple and/or elementary functions.

Comment: @jock43 I'm no expert but simply *calculus* would do the thing. *Precalculus* implies the high school methods to me while this will lead to something like Lambert W function in my opinion.

Comment: Setting $b=a(1-2^d)$ suggests itself. I don't know, maybe it makes it more complicated in the end.

Comment: why use base 2...seems arbitrary.  Using ln gets you in the same predicament.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to solve this numerically,
since no standard function will do it.

To get an initial value,
in $a(1 - 1/c)^{a - 1} = a - b$,
use the first two terms of the binomial theorem
to get
$(1 - 1/c)^{a - 1} \approx
1-(a-1)/c$.
This gives
$a(1-(a-1)/c) \approx a-b$
or
$a(c-a-1)\approx ac-bc$
or $ac-a^2-a \approx ac-bc$
or $a^2+a = bc$.
Completing the square,
$a^2+a+1/4 \approx bc$,
$(a+1/2)^2 \approx bc$,
$a \approx \sqrt{bc}-1/2$.